# Touchpad is missing and recognized as PS/2 Generic Mouse on Thinkpad E14

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad, 22.04

I am having a problem with my touchpad on Thinkpad E14. It worked well in the first Ubuntu 20.04 installation (Update: also after fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation), but after using it for some time (reboots or shutdowns), the essential scrolling feature with 2-fingers (multi-touch) stopped working.

In Settings > Mouse & Touchpad, the touchpad tab is also missing.

Using `xinput --list` in the terminal returned as below, showing that the touchpad now changed to mouse only:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I found several issues here related to this issue varied from 2012 until 2022, for Ubuntu version 20.04 to 22.04, but it seems this problem still persists. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing below, not sure which is actually the solution:

- remove `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
- in terminal, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled`
- reset BIOS setting to default, https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/de/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t570/20ha/troubleshoot/lpt001165

Answer (score 0):

If you're still experiencing this issue, in `/etc/default/grub` below the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

you should see

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line to be

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
```

Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks. I tried it but it still not working in my case :(